# NgRx Call dispatch Action in Angular router guard will execute infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

***Story:***

Hi everyone. I am a newbies in use NgRx library. In my angular project I use router guard to prevent unauthenticated user to unauthenticated website.

My ideal is call an rest api to verify local storage token content. When rest api result is "success", **before** return of(true), do **"store.dispatch(LoginSuccess)"** to update login auth information in Store.

***Problem:***

When do dispatch action. The "LoginSuccess" action always execute infinite loop even setting **{ dispatch: false }** in **@Effect()**. After try and search by google solution for it. This problem always in my project.
Hope some friends on stackoverflow can give me some help.~ thank you.

***part of codes:***

> auth.guard.ts

```js
.....
....
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    const authData: {email: string, token: string} = JSON.parse(
          String(localStorage.getItem('User')));

    const authToken = authData && authData.token;

    // loginServ is a REST API for verify token
    return this.loginServ.VerifyToken(authToken).pipe(
      concatMap((res: AuthResult) => {
        if (res.result === 'success') {

          this.store.dispatch(LoginSuccess({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            email: authData && authData.email,
            token: authToken,
            result: 'success',
            message: 'success'
          }));  // <-- execute action infinite.

          return of(true);
        } else {

          this.store.dispatch(LoginFailed({
            isAuthenticated: false,
            email: authData && authData.email,
            token: authToken,
            result: 'failed',
            message: 'token illegal'
          }));

          localStorage.removeItem('User');
          this.router.navigate(['']);
          return of(false);
        }
      })
    );
...
...
```

> action.ts:

```js
...
export const LoginSuccess = createAction(
  '[auth] Login Success',
  props<{
    isAuthenticated: boolean,
    email: string,
    token: string,
    result: string,
    message: string,
  }>()
);
....
...
```

> reducer.ts

```js
....
....
export const loginReducer = createReducer(
  defaultState,

  on(Login),

  on(LoginSuccess, (state, userInfo) => {
    console.log(state);     // <-- for debug.
    console.log(userInfo);  // <-- for debug.
    return {
      ...state,
      ...userInfo
    };
  }),

  on(LoginFailed, (state, result) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      ...result
    };
  }),
....
...
```

> effect.ts

```js
....
...
loginSuccess = createEffect(() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(LoginSuccess),
    map((user: any) => {

      console.log(user);
      const beStoreInfo = {
        email: user.email,
        token: user.token,
      };

      localStorage.setItem(
        'User',
        JSON.stringify(beStoreInfo));
        return {
          type: '[auth] Login Success',
          isAuthenticated: true,
          email: user.email,
          token: user.token,
          result: user.result,
          message: user.message
        };
    }),
  ), {dispatch: false});
....
...
```

> service_overview-routing.module.ts

```js
....
// using lazy loading module
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: ServiceOverviewComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ServiceOverviewRoutingModule { }
....
```

> app-routing.module.ts

**Using lazy load module.**

```js
....
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module')
    .then(m => m.LoginModule)},
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: () => import('./register/register.module')
    .then(m => m.RegisterModule)},
  { path: 'service_overview', loadChildren: () => import('./service-overview/service-overview.module')
    .then(m => m.ServiceOverviewModule)},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
....
```

***Environment:***

Angular Cli: 8.0.3

NgRx Store/Effect: 8.0.1

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

..Thanks

Comment: Please include your route configuration.

Comment: Thank you @Reactgular  . update my routing-module code :D

Answer (score 0):

Your login success effect returns another login success action resulting into infinite loop.

```
loginSuccess = createEffect(() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(LoginSuccess),
    map((user: any) => {

      console.log(user);
      const beStoreInfo = {
        email: user.email,
        token: user.token,
      };

      localStorage.setItem(
        'User',
        JSON.stringify(beStoreInfo));
        // remove this ⬇
        return {
          type: '[auth] Login Success',
          isAuthenticated: true,
          email: user.email,
          token: user.token,
          result: user.result,
          message: user.message
        };
        // end remove this ⬆
    }),
  ), {dispatch: false});
```

Comment: after remove return code, infinite loop always exist.

Comment: I find the solution by myself. This problem will be occur when I use "router.navigate" in NgRx-affects. It will trigger infinite loop by "auth.guard" .  When I remove router.navigate from NgRx-affects code. The problem will be solved and without remove "return code".